# Deuteronomy 32:27 Why would God fear these new gods?

Tags: deuteronomy

Deuteronomy 32

> <sup>**16**</sup>They provoked him to jealousy with strange gods, with abominations provoked they him to anger.
>
> <sup>**17**</sup>They sacrificed unto devils, not to God; to gods whom they knew not, to new gods that came newly up, whom your fathers feared not.

Israel's fathers did not fear these gods.

> <sup>**26**</sup>I said, I would scatter them into corners, I would make the remembrance of them to cease from among men:
>
> <sup>**27**</sup>Were it not that I feared the wrath of the enemy, lest their adversaries should behave themselves strangely, and lest they should say, Our hand is high, and the LORD hath not done all this.

Why then would God fear the wrath of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have interpreted the verse to mean God feared the other gods, is incorrect.

God of Heaven was concerned that the nations who He would use as instruments to chastise and punish His people, that they would be under the wrong impression. And draw the wrong conclusion.

They, the humans might think that because they defeated Israel/Judah therefore their gods are superior or they have the upper hand not understanding that it was God of Heaven who allowed this to happen as a corrective measure.

Therefore God is concerned how the other nations, their enemies, will interpret the correcting of Israel.

This is very evident from the text that follows

> ““For they are a nation void of counsel, and there is no understanding in them.”
> ‭‭Deuteronomy‬ ‭32:28‬ ‭

This is referring to the enemy nation, we know this based on the next portion of passage

> “How could one have chased a thousand, and two have put ten thousand to flight, **unless their Rock had sold them**, and the **Lord had given them up**?”
> ‭‭Deuteronomy‬ ‭32:30‬ ‭

So your question incorrectly assumes the enemies are the gods. It is referring to the nations that these gods were allotted verse 8.

> “When the Most High **gave to the nations** their inheritance, when he **divided mankind**, he fixed the borders of the peoples **according to the number of the sons of God**.”
> ‭‭Deuteronomy‬ ‭32:8‬ ‭

Or according to the number of gods

Answer (score 1):

God doesn't fear anyone.  There is not one verse in the entire bible that says otherwise.  He is the one eternal sovereign God who rules the universe and everyone and everything in it.  HE FEARS NO ONE!!!

Comment: God didn't want other nations to say of Israel, where is their god, demeaning God and questioning His faithfulness. This is not fear but caution that prevents those nations from questioning God's integrity.